# Using mLab on Google App Engine through Wiki.js (Connection timeout)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, google-app-engine

I'm trying to set up a Node.js application using wiki.js: https://github.com/Requarks/wiki

I just started with Google App Engine and using their Cloud Shell. I installed Wiki.js using their bash command and ran a command that ran a server on port 3000 which I then used Google's shell to view.

It brings you to Wiki.js' configuration UI where you insert info including the mongodb connection string.

I have a DB in mlab set up with a user. I tested it locally to make sure I can connect, but when I try to do this process through the Google App Engine "Web Preview" they have on their command line, on the step where I am to add the mongodb connection string, it times out, giving the error:

```
Error: failed to connect to server [secret.mlab.com:secret] on first connect [MongoError: connection 8 to secret.mlab.com:secret timed out]
```

(i hid the actual address)

So i'm wondering if I'm missing something with this Google App Engine, since this connects successfully on my localhost

Comment: On which port is Mongodb server listening? Note that there are limitations on outgoing connections in Cloud Shell [1]
[1]: https://cloud.google.com/shell/docs/limitations#outgoing_connections

Comment: I changed the web preview port to 8080 and it still couldn't connect